# Ajax FormData return null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I created a form. I am sending the data in this form as JSON.

If I just submit the formData (***I also change the controller to [FromBody] Image request***) and set the contentType and processData to false, the formData is not null.

I think "document" returns null because I am sending the data as JSON. How can I solve this issue I'm stuck in this issue.

***Ajax Request***

```
   let myProfile = {
        id: 0,
        title: "",
        text: "",
        document: File,
    };
    
        myProfile.title = "Lorem ipsum"; 
        myProfile.text = "Lorem ipsum"; 

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $('#file').get(0).files[0]);
        formData.append('fileName', $("#fileName").val());

        var myFile = formData.get('file');
        myProfile.document = myFile;

    $.ajax({
       url: `/admin/myprofile`,
       type: "POST",
       data: JSON.stringify(myProfile),
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: ....
```

***Cshtml***

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="document" asp-for="document" id="file" />
    </div>
```

***Controller***

```
    [HttpPost("myprofile")]
    public IActionResult MyProfile([FromBody] MyProfileDTO request)
    {
        return ...
    }
```

***Class***

```
    public class Image
    {
      public IFormFile file { get; set; }
      public string fileName { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyProfileDTO 
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public Image Document{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You can't `JSON.stringify` the formData object - that object needs to be sent as the parent object of the request. Instead use `formData.append()` to add the properties from `myProfile` as well as the image files and then use `data: formData, contentType: false, processData: false`

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Request

```
   let myProfile = {
        id: 0,
        title: "",
        text: "",
        document: File,
    };
    
        myProfile.title = "Lorem ipsum"; 
        myProfile.text = "Lorem ipsum"; 

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $('#file').get(0).files[0]);
        formData.append('title', myProfile.title);
        formData.append('text', myProfile.text);


    $.ajax({
       url: `/admin/myprofile`,
       type: "POST",
       data: formData ,
       contentType: "application/json",
       success: ....
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost("myprofile")]
    public IActionResult MyProfile([FromBody] MyProfileDTO request, IFormFile file)
    {
        return ...
    }
```

Class

```
    

    public class MyProfileDTO 
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```